# Zingchart - some points are hidden in the graph

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

I use Zingchart to plot some log Data therefore I need to display every single point in the graph. I activated the points attribute in the json(see

```js
$scope.graphoptions = {
            theme:"dark",
            "gui":{
              behaviors:[]
            },

            globals: {
              shadow: false,
              fontFamily: "Helvetica"
            },
            type: "line",
            plot: {
              aspect: "segmented",
              marker: {}
            },
            "legend":{
              margin :"5% 88%",
              layout: "float",
              fontSize : "10px",
              backgroundColor: "#888888",
              borderColor : "#000000",
              shadowColor : "transparent",
              toggleAction: "hide",
              item: {
                markerStyle : "circle",
                fontColor: "#ffffff"
              },
            },
            scaleX: {
              zooming: true,
              item: {
                fontColor: "white"
              },
              guide: {
                visible: false
              },
              "transform": {
                "type": "date",
                "all": "%G:%i",
              }
            },

            "scaleY": {
              zooming:true,
              lineColor : "#DDD",
              tick : {
                lineColor : "#DDD"
              },
              item : {
                fontColor : "#DDD"
              },
              refLine : {
                lineColor : "#DDD"
              },
            },

            tooltip : {
              //we have to store the tooltip fkt globally so its ouside angulars
              //scope thatswhy we have to pass the data to the function
              jsRule : "applyTooltip("+$scope.fileName+")",
              shadow:false
            },

            plotarea: {
              "adjust-layout":true,
              backgroundColor : '#272822'
            },
          }
```

for full json).

As you can see in this screenshot [image: graph without zoom]

Some points of the read Graph are drawn but none of the blue one.
When I zoom in:

[image: Graph with Zoom]

Some markers of the Blue graph are displayed. 
Is this a bug or do I have to activate an other attribute in the json I am not aware of.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your data is supposed to plot on those points, then you would need to increase the number of default markers drawn on the plot. By default, ZingChart calculates this number based upon the number of points, and the width of a chart.

- `maxNodes: N` where N is the maximum amount of nodes you want displayed at a given point. e.g. `maxNodes: 1000`
- If tooltips are important at a fine resolution, you would need to also change `maxTrackers: N`, where N is the amount of nodes to track for a tooltip. Do note that this will decrease performance heavily depending on the number of nodes to track. e.g. `maxTrackers: 1000`

Comment: Is there a way for the trackers to be 'spread' all over the graph? In my case I have data per second too, but I don't want a tracker every second.... one every 30 minutes / 1 hour, or in the pikes of the graph (local maximums and minimums) would be great. Currently the behavior is that if there are more points than trackers, they just get disabled.